# Prove $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\exp(xy)\cdot xy\cdot(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2} =0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to show that

> $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\exp(xy)\cdot xy\cdot(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2} =0.$$

Is it valid to do it like this:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \left|\frac{\exp(xy)\cdot xy\cdot(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\right| \leq \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} |\exp(xy)\cdot xy\cdot (x^2-y^2)|=0$$

Comment: How do you conclude that $\left|\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq1$? Since $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, it blows up to $\infty$ which causes your inequality to fail.

Comment: oh, yes! thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding the title, the exponential factor is actually pretty much irrelevant here since it just goes to one at the origin. As a hint to getting on the right track with this problem, it's often helpful to express things in polar coordinates

Comment: @FerdiK Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $e^{xy}\to 1$ and by polar coordinates

$$\left|\frac{xy\cdot(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\right|=r^2|(\cos \theta\sin \theta)(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)|\le r^2\to 0$$

Comment: Why go to polar coordinates? Seems unnecessary.

Comment: @zhw. I don't claim it is necessary but I think that in this way it is more clear to see. But of course it is only a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not valid. We have a/b 0 and b>1, but in this case we have the denominator going to less than 1, so that doesn't work. The $x^2+y^2$ suggests polar coordinates; that gives $$\frac{e^{r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)r^2(\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta))}{r^2}=$$$$e^{r^2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)}r^2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)(cos^2(\theta)-sin^2(\theta))=$$$$\frac{e^{r^2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)}r^2sin(2\theta)cos(2\theta)}2=$$$$\frac{e^{r^2sin(2\theta)/2}r^2sin(4\theta)}4 $$

Comment: I've corrected the Mathjax in the first line. Try it on the other lines.

Answer (score 0):

We may restrict the neibourhood to $x^2+y^2<1$, then $e^{xy}<2$ and
$$\left|\dfrac{e^{xy}xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leqslant\dfrac{2|xy|(|x|^2+|y|^2)}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant x^2+y^2$$

Comment: I would have thought the last term would be $2|xy|$ as it's simpler to think about.

Comment: @zhw. $|x^2+y^2|<\delta^2$, here $\delta=\min\{1,\sqrt{\varepsilon}\}$.

Comment: What I'm saying is why not just cancel the $x^2+y^2$ that is both upstairs and downstairs?